# Как распараллелить обработку изображения?

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность

Изображение (png-файл) подается на вход нейронной сети (многослойный перцептрон), которая классифицирует образы. В общем, все ок, но существующий код работает в одном потоке, а ядер - четыре штуки. Пока одно ядро обсчитывает сеть, остальные три простаивают. В вычислениях, которые производятся сетью, ничего особенного нет, обычные перемножения матриц чисел с плавающей точкой.

```
Y = W * X
```

Где (для однослойной сети) Y - вектор выходов сети, W - матрица весов сети, X - вектор входов сети. Как распараллелить вычисления?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете выполнять параллельные вычисления для нейронов в рамках одного слоя (т.е. грубо говоря, можно запустить по потоку на каждый нейров в слое), но, разумеется, нельзя параллелить вычисления нейронов в разных слоях (поскольку, для расчётов в следующем слое необходимо знать выходные сигналы всех нейронов предыдущего словя).

Comment: Я понял мысль: нужно считать каждый yi = ΣWij*xj в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Только не переборщите. Если у вас в слое чёрт знает сколько нейронов, то не стоит пытаться запускать несколько тысяч потоков. Стоит использовать ограниченный пул потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Если пишите на одном из языков .NET рекомендую обратить внимание на библиотеку TPL.